# How can I set a saved username and password combination in Firefox to work on multiple domains?

Tags: password-management, firefox

I like to use Firefox as my password manager. It tracks username and password combinations by domain. I can see why it was designed this way. You wouldn't want it to auto-fill a password on a completely unrelated site.

But, there are some sites I use where they actually have two (or more) domains, seemingly all connected to the same back end that stores my credentials. If I change my password on one, it affects how I must log in on the other. This means I have to manually go into Saved Logins in Firefox settings, find all of the sites (if I remember off the top of my head which ones they are), and update them all to my latest password.

It would be nice if Firefox allowed me to specify that a username and password is used on multiple domains, so that if I click "Update" in that prompt when I update my password for a service, I don't have to worry about manually syncing all the domains related to that service after I change the password.

When searching whether this question has already been posed, I found [Browser passwords used on multiple domains?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/207865/browser-passwords-used-on-multiple-domains), but that question appears to be the other side of my problem. That person is setting up a system that works like the system I describe. And the commenters let them know that the solution is not to design a system like this, but to instead use a proper authentication mechanism where the credential would only be associated with one domain. They cite OAuth as an example. My problem is that I'm not in control of the system I'm authenticating with. So I need to work around the problem, and this is one potential workaround I've identified.

Does Firefox support this? If so, how would I do it?